# Spell to Duplicate a PC

Tags: dnd-4e, spells, character-creation

Okay so here's the story: in an upcoming campaign, I will be sharing DMS duties with a player who's shown interest.

Now, we are planning on playing the same person, but the PC has mutiple personalities. So when I'm DMing, he plays one personality, and when he DMs I play the other. That way we won't have to explain two PCs jumping in and out of the party, plus it'd be fun to role play.

Thing is, if someone other than the two of us wanted to DM, even for one session, well... you can see how that'd be a problem.

QUESTION: Is there a spell that would split the character in two, if only (and preferably) for a small period of time? Maybe even an illusion or something.

We are playing in the Forgotten Realms, 4th edition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm unaware of a spell that does this. Please don't let that stop you.

This is one of those things that 4e just really has no interest in codifying. That doesn't make it impossible, it simply means that the explanation is intended to be narrative, and not mechanical.

So you both want to take a night off from DMing, someone else is going to step in and you guys are both going to play. Awesome! Make up a story that fits what might happen (a wizard did it! or "hey, guys, something funny happened when we walked through the rift there, my personalities seperated").

Don't sweat the mechanical details. Basically all mechanics would give you would be an unnecessary mechanical limitation. That's not useful unless your story calls for one.

This is just one more place where 4e's mechanics first approach actually shines. You are *completely in control* of the narrative explanation. The mechanical model is simply two different PCs.

Comment: +1, splitting a DID character into parts is definitely outside the scope of standard powers/rituals. Run through the idea with GM fiat/McGuffin-ness. If you ***REALLY*** want to mechanize it, have the GMs (including yourself) create a custom ritual to do what you want.